# Xamarin Forms Google AdMob errors when linking Sdk and User Assembly

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, admob

I have successfully added Google AdMob to my Xamarin Forms app. App is working fine on emulator as well as device.

Now I am trying to reduce apk size by turning on Linker with "Sdk and User Assembly" option, in Android project.

As soon as I turn on linker I get following error -

> Java.Lang.RuntimeException   Message=Unable to get provider
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.companyname.testapp-ja8UI5lHn0Hrtg1FqPOk8A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.companyname.testapp-ja8UI5lHn0Hrtg1FqPOk8A==/lib/x86,
>   /data/app/com.companyname.testapp-ja8UI5lHn0Hrtg1FqPOk8A==/base.apk!/lib/x86,
>   /system/lib]]

Any suggestion on how do I fix this error and still reduce apk size?

**Update**

All the NuGet packages are up-to-date with latest version.

For Android - 
[image]

For .NET Standard 2.0 - 
[image]

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Google AdMob?  Have a look at [this thread](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/511#issuecomment-438153984) may help.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I already APPLICATION_ID added.

Comment: However I didn’t understand the selected answer. “Compile com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads”. How do I compile it?

Comment: My suggestion is update those relevant nuget package to the latest version and try again.

Comment: All the NuGet packages are already latest. Updated question with screenshots.

Comment: I have same problem, did you finally find a solution?